# Is there an abbr. for 'Up To Today/Date' like YTD?

Tags: abbreviations

While giving a short comment for the report, to describe that the data is counted from the beginning to today. It's just like `YTD` - `Year To Day`, except that I don't care about the starting date here. Is there such an abbreviation? Do we use `UTT` - `Up To Today`?

Comment: If you don't give a starting date, how will people know what the figure represents (even if you do find an abbreviation for it)?

Comment: YTD = Year to **date** -  https://www.investopedia.com/terms/y/ytd.asp -- UTT -> https://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/UTT

Comment: @KillingTime usually with a given context, the starting date could be "the kick off date of the current project we're talking about"

Answer (score 1):

I've seen "To Date" used for just that purpose.

But I'm unsure if it is abbreviated to TD. I have seen UTD used for the purpose but I don't think its nearly as recognizable as YTD.

Comment: People will usually recognise the meaning of "Year TD", and by extension they would recognise "Month TD" or "Week TD". But "TD" would not normally be used on its own, and as you say, the full phrase is "year to date" (apparently a shortened form of "from the beginning of the year to the current date".